# How to access provider's supported types in Android Wear 2.0

Tags: android-wear-2.0

I am starting to work on the new Android Wear 2.0 Api's specifically Complications. I have found out that the Complications will default to the "easiest" supported type that the provider also supports, such as the Android Wear Battery Life will default to TYPE_SHORT_TEXT when the complication supports TYPE_SHORT_TEXT as well as TYPE_RANGED_VALUE. So I am wondering if there is a way to access the types the provider supports (which is added in the manifest for provider as a service) as shown below.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.wearable.complications.SUPPORTED_TYPES"
            android:value="RANGED_VALUE,SHORT_TEXT,LONG_TEXT"/>
```

Is there a way to access the array of supported types of a provider?

EDIT:

I found the way to access the supported types of a provider through reading the manifest's meta data where the supported types for the service is needed to be declared.

```
ComponentName service = new ComponentName(this, DataProvider.class);
        try {
            Bundle bundle = getPackageManager().getServiceInfo(service, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;
            if(bundle != null) {
                for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                    Object value = bundle.get(key);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,
                            value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
                }
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Though I am still wondering about how to access the supported type of Google's system built providers (under AppName: Android Wear) such as Watch battery, World clock, etc.

Any ideas?